# Is there a faster way to compress files/make an archive in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

I'm making archive of a folder that has around ~1 GB of files in it. It takes like 1 or 2 minutes but I want it to be faster.

I am making a UI app in Python that allows you to ZIP files (it's a project, I know stuff like 7Zip exists lol), and I am using a folder with ~1GB of files in it, like I said. The program won't accept files over 5GB because of the speed.

Here is how I compress/archive the folder:
`shutil.make_archive('files_archive', 'zip', 'folder_to_archive')`

I know I can change the format but I'm not sure which one is fast and can compress well.

So, my end goal is to compress files fast, whilst also reducing size.

Comment: tar is likely the fastest, but also provides effectively no compression.  otherwise zip is probably the runner up

Comment: "well I do, the folder has to be under 5GB." "I'm making archive of a folder that has around ~1 GB of files in it." I can't understand. Doesn't the folder already meet the requirement? Therefore, why do we have to do anything? Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, and try to identify clear requirements. "Here is how I compress/archive the folder: shutil.make_archive('files_archive', 'zip', 'folder_to_archive')" Okay, so **what is wrong** with this approach?

Comment: Hi, I wanted to update you on something: The thing I was making was for other people to use. *They* might try to zip folders/files over 5GB which is why my program doesn't accept that because it would be too slow. So, I needed a way to compress files fast so I can support up to 10GB instead or more. Not everything is going to be ran on my machine. I might send the script to friends too. Please, find common sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`shutil.make_archive`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.make_archive) offers `zip`, `tar`, `gztar`, `bztar` or `xztar` as archive formats.

`tar` is uncompressed so will be fastest, but uncompressed.

If you want to have faster compression than the built in formats, you will need an external command.

A common fast compression algorithm is [LZ4](https://github.com/lz4/lz4).

I recommend you look into https://morotti.github.io/lzbench-web/ for various compression algorithms, and their compression ratio over speed.

But you will likely have to benchmark on a sample of own data.

Comment: How do I put LZ4 into make_archive? When I tried it, it said `unknown archive format 'lz4'`. I have read your answer, and I do know that LZ4 is an algorithm, not a format but I thought I'd try it.

Comment: If you want to stick with `shutil.make_archive`, you’ll need to create an archiving function similar to [`_make_tarball`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e83f88a455261ed53530a960f1514ab7af7d2e82/Lib/shutil.py#L884) or [`_make_zipfile`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e83f88a455261ed53530a960f1514ab7af7d2e82/Lib/shutil.py#L954) for LZ4 and register it with [`shutil.register_archive_format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.register_archive_format), otherwise, make the tar archive and run `lz4` externally with subprocess.